# To find a Git Repo by its ID

Tags: git

**How can you search all GIT's IDs in your computer?**

I created a Git repo at Github. One of my folders has an arrow and a similar figure as `f1f633`. I know that the repo is one of my other repos.

However, I would like to be able to search repo.
I searched the figure at Github and at Google unsuccessfully.

Perhaps, there is some tool which allows me to search all IDs in my computer by Git.

Comment: Please, move it then to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to, within each repository, use `git cat-file -e` to check if the repository has that object:

```
git cat-file -e f1f633 2>/dev/null && echo "found"
```

Just combine it with any way of running within all git repositories in your machine, for instance:

```
find / -name objects | fgrep .git/objects | while read dir; do
    (cd "$dir" && git cat-file -e f1f633 2>/dev/null && echo "found: $dir")
done
```

You can also use other forms of `git cat-file` to get more data about the object; see the manual for details.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to combine find with "[git rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) --verify" or "[git cat-file](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cat-file.html) -e"; assuming that you have non-bare repositories only:

```
find / -name ".git" -type d -print |
while read repo; do
    git --git-dir="$repo" cat-file -e f1f633 2>/dev/null && echo "found: $repo"
done
```

Note that you should check if found object is what you searched for with "git show f1f633", as different repositories can have different objects with the same prefix (partial SHA-1).